# Terraform destroy add the same resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, module, terraform

I'm facing a difficult issue to resolve.
I'm terraforming the deployement for multiple ressources on GCP's plateform.
Those ressources are all included in the terraform GCP's network module. (https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-network).

I'm building 2 projects with VPC (shared) and some subnetworks. Easy at first glance.
First terraform init/plan & apply was Ok, the tfstate file is on gcs backend with versionning set on true.

Today, I launch an terraform plan on it to check if everything was ok before doing some modifications.

The output of the plan is telling me that terraform wants to destroy some resources ... and recreate (adding) ... strictly the same resources ...

The code is on our bitbucket repo, no changes on it till the last apply who was ok.
I tried to retreive an old version of the tfstate files, disable the gcs backend to debug and correct it localy, but I can't find a way to refresh the current state.

I tried those tricks :

- terraform refresh
- terraform import (40 ressources with my little hands ... and even if import commands are working, the plan command still want to destroy my existing resources to recreate strictly the same ...)

So I'm wondering if you already encountered the same problem.
If yes, how you managed it ?

I can share my source on demand.

Terraform v0.12.9

- provider.google v2.19.0
- provider.google-beta v3.3.0
- provider.null v2.1.2
- provider.random v2.2.1

Answer (score 2):

Ok, big rookie mistake, terraform providers save my day. No versions was set on the source's module version ... I just define it, replan, everything was fine again.